# async pipes в Angular 7

Tags: angular, асинхронность, pipes

В mainPage.component мне нужно асинхронно получить данные о текущем пользователе и передать их в nav-bar.component, а там уже отобразить что нужно, с помощью *ngIf.

Мое приложение использует API Вконтакте.

У меня есть два основных сервиса: один получает данные от VK, другой от моей БД на хостинге. Делаю так: получаю данные от VK, проверяю права пользователя в своей БД и возвращаю готовый объект (пользователя с полем "role").

Так получаю пользователя:

```
getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return new Observable<User> ((observer: Observer<User>) => {
        VK.api("users.get", {"fields": "photo_50", "v":"5.92"},
        function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                console.error('Не удалось получить данные о пользователе');
            }              
            let res = data.response[0];                                      
            let temp = new User(0,'','','',0,0);
            temp.id = res.id;
            temp.first_name = res.first_name;
            temp.last_name = res.last_name;
            temp.photo = res.photo_50;
            observer.next(temp);
            observer.complete(); 
            });
        }
        );    
}
```

Так получаю права пользователя из БД:

```
checkRole(user: User): Observable<User> {
    let params = new HttpParams().append('queryType', 'CHECK_Role')
                                 .append('user_id', '' + user.id);
    return this.http.post<any>(this.url, params).pipe(
                                                 map(res => 
                                                    new User (user.id, 
                                                            user.first_name, 
                                                            user.last_name,
                                                            user.photo,
                                                            user.rating,                                                                          
                                                            Number(res[0].role)))
                                                 );
}
```

Еще есть сервис userService, который просто последовательно выполняет эти два запроса:

```
getViewer(): Observable<User> {
    return this.vkAPIService.getUser().pipe(
                                concatMap(res => this.dbService.checkRole(res))
                                ).pipe(take(1));                                                                                                                       
}
```

В основном компоненте следующий код:

```
viewer$: Observable<User>;

constructor (private userService: UserService) {   
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.viewer$ = this.userService.getViewer();
}
```

И в шаблоне основного компонента:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(viewer$ | async) === null">
  LOADING...
</ng-container>

<nav-bar [viewer] = "viewer$"></nav-bar>
```

Итог - ничего не работает, хотя аналогичные конструкции уже есть в моем приложении и работают отлично.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел баг в методе getUser(). Все заработало как надо после того, как вынес observer.next() за операторные скобки callback-функции запроса API ВКонтакте. Принял решение использовать в этом методе Promise вместо Observable. И функцию getViewer() немного поправил. В итоге getUser() выглядит так:

```
getUser(): Promise<User> {
    return new Promise<User> ((resolve, reject) => {                                      
        let temp = new User(0,'','','',0,0);
        VK.api("users.get", {"fields": "photo_50", "v":"5.92"},
        function (data) {
            if (!data) 
                reject(console.error('Ошибка: не удалось получить пользователя'));              
            let res = data.response[0];
            temp.id = res.id;
            temp.first_name = res.first_name;
            temp.last_name = res.last_name;
            temp.photo = res.photo_50;
            resolve(temp);
            })
        }
        );
}
```

А метод getViewer() так:

```
getViewer(): Observable<User> {
    let observable = from(this.vkAPIService.getUser());
    return observable.pipe(take(1),
                            concatMap(res => this.dbService.checkRole(res)),
                            tap(res =>  console.log('checkRole отработал: ', res))
                            );                                                                                                                      
}
```

Comment: Спасибо пользователю https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/303477/overthesanity за то, что откликнулся и помог разобраться в деталях.